# get Data outside subscribe method in angular 13

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs-observables

I have 2 functions in ngOninit

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.getRowData();
  this.getWrapperGridData(); 
}
```

GetRowData() is used to subscribe to a service and it looks like this

```
  getRowData() {
  this.showDataServiceSubscription = this.heroService.showData().subscribe((data) => {
    this.onlineData = data;
  console.log('onlineData 1',this.onlineData);

  })
}
```

In getWrapperGridData, I am calling this.onlineData again like this

```
  getWrapperGridData(){
    console.log('onlineData',this.onlineData);
  }
```

The problem is I am getting the result of onlineData inside getRowData method as it is written inside subscribe but I am getting undefined inside getWrapperGridData. How do we fix this?

Comment: You can use `switchMap` operator from RxJs or return a promise in `getRowData` and use `.then` to call `getWrapperGridData`.

Comment: You could also just return the observable from `getRowData()` and subscribe to it inside of your `ngOnInit()` method.

Comment: Can you please share the snippet of what you're saying?

Comment: You call the functions synchronously directly after each other, but the response of the `showData()` subscription is asynchronous and is assigned to `this.onlineData` after the `getWrapperGridData` function has already been executed. A simple solution would be to move the function call `this.getWrapperGridData();` from the `ngOnInit()` to the subscription block of `getRowData()` after the line `this.onlineData = data;`.

Answer (score 2):

it depend on what you want to do inside `getWrapperGridData` ( right now you only log it to console )

you can use `rxjs pipe` like this to manipulate the data return from the `showData` method.

```
 getRowData() {
   this.showDataServiceSubscription = 
       this.heroService.showData()
        .pipe(tap(data => {
           // here you can do what you plan to to do inside getWrapperGridData
          }))
        .subscribe((data) => {
          this.onlineData = data;
       console.log('onlineData 1',this.onlineData);

   })
 }
```

--> it's not a best practice to `subscribe` inside the `.ts` file, instead considered store the `Observable` itself inside the variable, for example

```
 this.onlineData$ = this.heroService.showData();
```

and use `async pipe`, see [Docs](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with subscribing other than you need to remember to unsubscribe (usually in `OnDestroy`.  That's usually not very ergonomic, but sometimes that's what required and is a normal practice.

Comment: of course, sometimes you need to do it, but it can cause problems - more than forgetting to unsubscribe - so I will try to avoid it as much as I can, most of the time if you know to use `rxjs` operators - you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you face is that the calls to `getRowData` and `getWrapperGridData` respectively are synchronous, the call to the backend and retrieval of the data is asynchronous though. That means by the time `getWrapperGridData` is executed, `getRowData` and data fetching is likely not done yet.
Because `getWrapperGridData` seems to depend on the data of `getRowData` you can chain the calls together using [rxjs switchmap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap). The two backend calls will then be chained and executed one after another.

Note: Inside `switchMap` you need to return an Observable. I assume that you need to fetch data asynchronously inside `getWrapperGridData`. If that is not the case, use `tap` instead of `switchMap`.

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class Foo implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit(){
    this.getData();
  }
  
  getData() {
    this.heroService.showData().pipe(
      switchMap((onlineData) => {
        this.onlineData = onlineData; // In case you need this globally

        return this.gridWrapperService.getData(onlineData);
      })
    ).subscribe((gridWrapperData) => {
      // Deal with the data.
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: getGridWrapperData is a sync function. It just needs the output of onlineData

Comment: Then go with the answer provided by @Eli Porush